# SQL to copy and save in JSON format

Tags: mysql, sql

I am on mysql server 5.7.27 and trying to copy data from one table to another table with formatted json value.

Let's say there are two tables:-

```
files(id, applicant_id, passport, license);
attachments(id, applicant_id, passport, license);
```

passport and license column in `files` table has string datatype carrying their literal value while in attachments the datatype is defined as json and needs to be saved along with other data such as file name.

I want to copy data from `files` table to `attachments` table with some additional formatting for json data.

```
INSERT INTO attachments (applicant_id, license) FROM files (applicant_id, '{"\name\": \"Driving License\", "\file\": license}');
```

But this gave me an error:-
***3140 Invalid JSON text: "Invalid value."***

What is the correct syntax for parsing the value of `license`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are looking for an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO attachments (applicant_id, license)
SELECT
    applicant_id,
    CONCAT('{"\name\": \"Driving License\", "\file\": \"', license, '\"}')
FROM files;
```

Here I am using `CONCAT` to build the JSON literal value you want with the license value from the `files` table.